# Правильная реализация в программе MemoryCache

Tags: c#, кэширование

Создаю приложение `WinForms`. В главном классе Form1 имею объект `MemoryCache cache`. 
В остальных классах необходимо узнать, есть ли уже запись по данному ключу, если есть - получить, если нет - рассчитать значение, добавить в кэш и присвоить значение к списку `List<double`
Как лучше такое реализовать? 
Грубо говоря :
 1. Есть похожий ключ в кэше?
 2. Нет - делаем расчет и добавляем в кэш, есть - берем из кэша и не делаем расчет.
Как это выглядит в коде?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Мне кажется стоит использовать MemeryCache.Default и метод https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee395901(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как бы это сделал я:

Определяем  интерфейс для источника данных

```
public interface IDataProvider
{
    List<double> GetData(int param1, string param2);
}
```

Обычный наш источник данных:

```
internal class MyDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    public List<double> GetData(int param1, string param2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Provider called");
        return Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Далее, пишем кеширующий декоратор

```
internal class MyCachedDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    IDataProvider _inner;
    ICache<List<double>> _cache;    
    private object _locker = new object();

    public MyCachedDataProvider(IDataProvider inner, ICache<List<double>> cache)
    {
        _inner = inner;
        _cache = cache;
    }

    private static string GenerateKey(int param1, string param2)
    {
        return $"{param1} - {param2}";      
    }

    public List<double> GetData(int param1, string param2)
    {
        var key = GenerateKey(param1, param2);
        var result = _cache.Get(key);
        if (result == null)
        {
            // лочим только чтобы 2 раза не генерить данные в многопоточном сценарии. 
            lock (_locker)
            {
                result = _cache.Get(key);
                if (result == null)
                {
                    result = _inner.GetData(param1, param2);
                    _cache.Add(key, result);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Соответственно, нам надо кеш. Заводим интерфейс

```
public interface ICache<T>
{
    void Add(string key, T value);
    T Get(string key);
}
```

Наивная реализация

```
internal class Cache<T> : ICache<T>
{
    MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    TimeSpan expireTime;

    public Cache()
    {
        expireTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        //cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    }

    public void Add(string key, T value)
    {
        var cacheItem = new CacheItem(key, value);      
        // Ваши политики протухания кеша
        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy() { SlidingExpiration = expireTime };
        //var policy = new CacheItemPolicy() {AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.Add(expireTime)};
        cache.Add(cacheItem, policy);
    }

    public T Get(string key)
    {
        var item = cache.GetCacheItem(key);
        var ii = cache[key];
        return (T)cache.Get(key);
    }
}
```

Как это можно использовать:

```
var dataProvider = new MyCachedDataProvider( new MyDataProvider(), new Cache<List<double>>());

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    dataProvider.GetData(i%10, "some string");
}
```

Как передать в другой класс

```
var form = new MyForm(dataProvider);

// Где форма

public class MyForm : Form
{
    IDataProvider _dataProvider ;

    public MyForm(IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        _dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Как передать в метод

```
var anotherform = new MyAnotherForm();
anotherform.SomethingToDo(dataProvider);

// Где форма

public class MyAnotherForm : Form
{
    public void SomethingToDo(IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            dataProvider.GetData(i%10, "some string");
        }
    }
}
```

Смысл декоратора в том, чтобы скрыть от клиентов, что используется кеш. Потому при добавлении кеширования я не менял интерфейс источника данных. А ключ для кеширования генерируется на основе входящих параметров.

Comment: У меня еще прошлая Ваша реализация многопоточности в моей программе, теперь еще и кэш будет. Просто из-за личных проблем голова не варит совсем, а делать нужно, поэтому только сюда и обращаюсь. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @Fresto Пожалуйста. Кстати, обратите внимание на мою реализацию кеша - я там поставил время  2 секунды + политика протухания SlidingExpiration, вам скорее всего что то другое надо будет прописать вместо этого. И если мой ответ вам поможет решить проблему, то отметьте его как ответ.

Comment: Хорошо, разберусь во всем этом.

Comment: Извините, может быть я слишком глуп для этого кода. Чтобы добавить данные, мы должны создать объект класса `Cache<T>`. Добавить в него данные и получаем через объект `MyCachedDataProvider`?
И еще, где именно реализована проверка на уже существующие данные с таким же ключом? 
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Fresto ```MyCachedDataProvider``` сам добавляет данные в кеш, если их там нет. Как понять, что их там нет? Попробовать получить данные и если вернется Null, то их нет. Сама проверка в```if (result == null)``` в методе ```GetData()``` класса ```MyCachedDataProvider```. Сам класс ```MyCachedDataProvider``` - по сути просто декоратор. Его задача - он принимает вызовы от клиентов, проверяет если данные в кеше есть - вернуть их, если нет, то запросить данные из источника данных, добавить в кеш и вернуть.

Comment: Просто, метод GetData() не имеет входных параметров и тогда получается, как мне получить данные именно по какому-то ключу? 
Я представляю, что имею объект общего кэша, в который я добавляю по ключу данные и получаю по ключу данные. Я уже полностью пересмотрел всё, но так и не понимаю, как мне элементарно добавить 3 разных списка в кэш по ключу и получить их по этому же ключу? Здесь при создание объекта мы используем кэш уже имеющихся данных, как я понял, но где я тогда добавляю все данные и т п?

Comment: @Fresto обновил ответ, добавил параметры в GetData. Я не вижу ваш код и не знаю, какие параметры вам нужны для генерации списков, потому добавил 2 параметра и считаю ключ на их основе.

Comment: Вот мой основной файл, в котором я провожу расчеты http://dropmefiles.com/MpYnN

Comment: Извините, если я достаю этим, просто вы очень многое сделали для данного вопроса и всё закрывать и прописать что-то своё было бы неблагодарно, поэтому и спрашиваю про Вашу реализацию данного вопроса именно для своего кода

Comment: И всё же я понял, как с этим кодом работать. Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Я не могу поглядеть ваш файл (фаерволл не пустит), но рад что мой ответ вам помог :)