# Где и сколько хранится статик переменная в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

Столкнулся с неясностью. В asp.net глобальная переменная

```
static List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Menu = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
```

Хранится для всех пользователей какое-то время (Все кто заходят на страницу видят результат выполнения первой, т.к. среди кода существует проверка if(Menu.Count>0)return), через какое-то N время, которое никак не задано кодом - переменная очищается и происходит взятие данных из БД.

Помогите,пожалуйста разобраться, как всё это объясняется?

Comment: И где (класс, неймспейс) у вас в коде объявлена эта переменная? Вообще-то в классическом asp.net [глобальные переменные делаются](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5118610/5752652) через класс `Application["МояПеременная"]`.

Comment: У вас в коде список, а пишете вы по кеш с заданным временем жизни объектов в нем

Comment: перед public void Page_Load просто среди кода static List... Про глобальную посмотрю, интересно.

Comment: @tym32167, а заданное время жизни- это сколько и где оно задалось?

Comment: Заданного времени жизни в вашем коде нет

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737826/Правильная-реализация-в-программе-memorycache/737848#737848) пример работы с кешем в памяти. Хз подойдет оно вам или нет, но для понимания думаю будет полезно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Статические переменные в ASP.NET хранятся, как и в любом приложении на .NET, до тех пор пока живет приложение.

Приложение может быть выгружено из памяти по следующим причинам:

1. любое изменение в папке bin;
2. изменение файла конфигурации;
3. просто по истечении тайм-аута неактивности или превышении лимитов памяти, запросов или времени работы (эти параметры задаются в настройках пула приложений IIS);
4. при перезапуске сервера.

Отдельно отмечу, что каждый запуск отладки в студии ведет к повторной сборке, что означает изменение файлов в папке bin. Кроме того, при использовании IIS Express сервер останавливается по окончанию отладки.

Comment: думаю, что всё-таки тайм-аут не активности, покапаюсь с IIS