# Асинхронное чтение одного Stream двумя потребителями

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, .net-core, async-await

Пытался придумать, как одновременно писать получаемые с сервера данные в десериализтор и файл, используемый в будущем как кеш для повторяющихся запросов. Ищу решение, чтобы не читать полностью ответ с сервера и не копировать его вручную побуферно.

Вот моя жалкая попытка, закомментировал то, что у меня не получилось. С закомментированными строчками все работает, а если раскомментировать - десериализатор падает, по вполне понятным причинам.

```csharp
private static async Task<T> HttpAPIRequest<T>(string url, string path)
{
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    //using FileStream fileStream = File.Create(path);
    //Task fileTask = responseStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    ValueTask<T> jsonTask = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseStream);
    //await fileTask;
    return await jsonTask;
}
```

Но как такое сделать правильно?

У меня есть сейчас рабочий код, но там сначала я полностью гружу ответ в `byte[]` массив, а затем отправляю этот массив в десериализатор и файл.

Comment: Одновременно вряд-ли, так как Streams не threadsafe. Базовая часть задачи будет решена, если после записи в файл (дождавшись завершения таски), сдвинуть позицию оригинального потока в начало и передать в десериализацию. Обычно передавая Stream куда-то, то мы обязаны гарантировать что пока тот не завершит свои действия над Stream, мы с этим потоком ничего не будем делать, иначе могут быть ошибки из-за чтений и сдвига позиций.

Comment: 1) вы не можете читать файл в 2 потоках одновременно 2) Вам не надо читать/писать в файл на каждый запрос. Операция с файлом - медленная операция. Читате нужные вам данные из памяти. Есть столько [много разных решений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737848/179763) для кеша и ни одно из них не подразумевает запись/чтение из файла на каждый запрос. Даже логгеры, типа log4net или nlog используют синхронизацию и буфер для записи в файл, так как работа с вводом/выводом на кажое логгирование это медленно.

Comment: Если же вам надо одавать контент файла каждый раз, то просто разрешите клиенту качать файлы с диска напрмямую, пусть проблема одновременного чтения файла будет головной болью веб сервера

Comment: @tym32167 я не отдаю данные, я их получаю из API и десереализую, а чтобы мне за одним и тем же не ходить в API много раз (данные там меняются редко), я кеширую это на диск. А реализация кеша сейчас - дело десятое, с этим я еще поработаю, но позже. Спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока я ждал ответа, прогресс не стоял на месте, и у меня все-таки удалось раскусить этот вопрос.

Суть ТЗ:

- Форкнуть стрим асинхронно так, чтобы он одновременно писался в несколько стримов-приемников
- При этом, каждый из приемников может завершить свою работу раньше остальных
- Чтение из стрима-источника должно происходить с такой скоростью, с какой читает самый быстрый приемник
- Если поток-источник медленный (а он всегда медленный в моем случае), то приемники должны ожидать появления новых данных

Решение пришло откуда не ждали: `IEnumerator`.

```csharp
public sealed class ConcurrentStreamReader : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stream _inputStream;
    private readonly MemoryStream _memoryStream;
    private readonly int _bufferSize;
    private readonly IProgress<long> _progress;
    private bool disposed;

    public ConcurrentStreamReader(Stream inputStream) : this(inputStream, null) { }

    public ConcurrentStreamReader(Stream inputStream, IProgress<long> progress) : this(inputStream, 81920, 0, progress) { }

    public ConcurrentStreamReader(Stream inputStream, int bufferSize, int capacity, IProgress<long> progress)
    {
        _memoryStream = new MemoryStream(capacity);
        _inputStream = inputStream;
        _bufferSize = bufferSize;
        _progress = progress;
    }

    public Stream CreateNewStream() => new BlockingStream(ReadStream().GetEnumerator(), _memoryStream);

    public async Task CopyToAsync(Stream outputStream)
    {
        foreach (ReadOnlyMemory<byte> buffer in ReadStream())
        {
            await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> ReadStream()
    {
        long position = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];
        int bytesRead;
        while (true)
        {
            if (position == _memoryStream.Length)
            {
                lock (_inputStream)
                {
                    if (position < _memoryStream.Length) continue;
                    bytesRead = _inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                    if (bytesRead == 0) break;
                    lock (_memoryStream)
                    {
                        _memoryStream.Position = _memoryStream.Length;
                        _memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                _progress?.Report(_memoryStream.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                lock (_memoryStream)
                {
                    _memoryStream.Position = position;
                    bytesRead = _memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                }
            }
            position += bytesRead;
            yield return new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !disposed)
        {
            disposed = true;
            _memoryStream?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public sealed class BlockingStream : Stream
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> _sourceEnumerator;
    private readonly MemoryStream _stream;
    private long _position;

    private BlockingStream() { }

    public BlockingStream(IEnumerator<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> sourceEnumerator, MemoryStream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _sourceEnumerator = sourceEnumerator;
        _position = 0;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        long tail = _position + count;
        while (tail >= _stream.Length && _sourceEnumerator.MoveNext()) { }
        int bytesRead;
        lock (_stream)
        {
            _stream.Position = _position;
            bytesRead = _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }
        _position += bytesRead;
        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Position { get => throw new NotSupportedException(); set => throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    public override void Flush() => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

И вот так вот оно теперь используется.

```csharp
private async Task<T> HttpAPIRequest<T>(string url, string path)
{
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    using ConcurrentStreamReader reader = new ConcurrentStreamReader(responseStream);
    using FileStream fileStream = File.Create(path);
    using Stream deserealizerStream = reader.CreateNewStream();
    ValueTask<T> jsonTask = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(deserealizerStream);
    await reader.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    return await jsonTask;
}
```

Если есть советы, что допилить, или где мне не хватило ума сделать нормально - пишите в комментариях. Всем спасибо, кто пытался помочь.

Comment: А не надо ли с AsyncStream.Position обращаться через Interlocked? А то как-то странно - меняете вы её внутри lock-ов, а читаете без них. Если архитектура точно 64-бит, то должно быть вроде всё ок, ну а если вдруг нет? )

Comment: @CrazyElf точно 64, операция чтения должна быть атомарная. Но интересное замечание, спасибо. :)

Comment: Да меня самого забодало эти Interlocked писать, но что делать ))  Некрасивая конструкция, надеюсь со временем придумают вместо Interlocked какой-то синтаксический сахар для красоты (а может и уже придумали).

Comment: В финализаторе ерунда, это я по поводу того что вы вызываете Dispose только когда он был явно вызван.

Comment: @ヒミコ исправил, спасибо!

Comment: @apeot, вы немного не поняли, вам необходимо вызывать Dispose для MemoryStream, в любом случае... Только если объект уже не был освобождён, тогда, его не нужно вызывать, и при явном вызове, обнулите все поля. А точнее именно для MemoryStream, и выполняйте проверку на то, что объект уже освобождён, и бросайте исключение, в случае обращения к освобожденному объекту, я надеюсь вы помните что ссылка не обнуляется автоматически.

Comment: @ヒミコ что сделать понял, а вот чем я рискую сейчас - нет. А финализер я убрал за ненадобностью, потому что у меня нет неуправляемых ресурсов.

Answer (score 2):

Как насчёт такого способа:

```
private static async Task<T> HttpAPIRequest<T>(string url, string path)
{
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    using Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    using FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path);
    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // выбрать размер буфера
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        var task1 = fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        var task2 = memoryStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    }
    // memoryStream.Position = 0;
    ValueTask<T> jsonTask = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(memoryStream);
    return await jsonTask;
}
```

Comment: Да, такой вариант с побуферным копированием рассматриваю, если не найдется более элегантного решения или реализации асинхронного стрима. Здесь надо бы перенести запуск десереализатора до цикла и закрыть `MemoryStream` перед возвратом из метода.

Comment: `File.OpenWrite(path);` это придется ка кто синхронизировать

Comment: @tym32167 На каждый уникальный запрос в API пишется отдельный файл, здесь запись возможна только из этого в данный момент выполняемого метода. И на каждый запуск процесса получения данных из API нет повторяющихся запросов, следовательно пока пишется файл, читать его никто пытаться не будет. Так что здесь все нормально. Повторный запрос тех же самых данных возможен только после перезапуска приложения. Самих данных не так много, около 100 мегабайт, поэтому они спокойно хранятся в объектах в памяти, и я их не выгружаю. Пользователю разрешен запуск только одного экземпляра приложения.

Comment: @aepot ну если вы знаете, что делаете, то тогда все хорошо :)

Comment: подскажите, что-то изменится если в конце написать `return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(memoryStream);`?

Comment: @4per - вроде, ничего не изменится. Однако, как правильно написал aepot в первом комментарии, правильнее перенести строку десериализации выше. PS: я код писал прямо в браузере, не проверял.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я уже проверил, если перенести выше - не будет работать, так как сериализатор просто заберет из стрима то что там на момент его запуска есть, и вывалится. Сейчас работаю над решением с потокобезопасным энумератором входящего стрима, и вроде-как что-то начинает получаться, осталось только грамотно выходящие стримы прикрутить. Позже скину наработки в вопрос, или в ответ...