# Несколько читателей и 1 записывающий поток через SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, а можно ли как-то реализовать читателей и писателя через SemaphoreSlim.

Когда 1 читатель и писатель, то все просто.

А как быть, когда их несколько?

Comment: Когда пишете – блокируете ресурс, записываете новое значение, разблокируете ресурс; когда читаете – просто читаете, т. к. чтение не меняет значение ресурса и является автоматически синхронизированной операцией

Comment: Почему не ReaderWriterLock?

Comment: Читатели и писатели чего? `Stream`? Посмотрите [`Stream.Synchronized`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.synchronized?view=netframework-4.8) ([исходники](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L1071)). Уже все изобретено.

Comment: Вокруг `Synchronized` можно еще навесить свой лок, который будет отвечать за то, что `.Position` не поменяется, пока идет чтение, и для каждого читателя и писателя сделать свой позишн. Я делал что-то подобное на базе `NetworkStream` вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1144090/373567). Вот еще [нагуглил](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3729877/12888024).