# Как вычеслить прогресс хеширования System.IO.Hashing?

Tags: c#, хеширование

Хочу перейти с неофициальных реализаций хэш-функций на официальный  [System.IO.Hashing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.hashing?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0). Но я совершенно не понимаю, как сделать чтобы осуществлялся рапорт о прогрессе хэширования?
Намерен использовать алгоритм XxHash3, но думаю что это не важно.

На данный момент я высчитываю хэш так (без отображения прогресса):

```
private string GetXxHash3(string filename)
{
    var hashAlgorithm = new XxHash3();
    using (Stream entryStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filename))
        hashAlgorithm.Append(entryStream);
    
    return BitConverter.ToString(hashAlgorithm.GetHashAndReset()).Replace("-", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: `рапорт о прогрессе хэширования` - что это значит?

Comment: @tym32167, это значит сообщать о прогрессе. Я обычно использую для этих целей класс IProgress<double>. Там есть метод .Report(T).

Comment: А сколько часов надо ждать, чтобы это прохешировалось? Реализуйте свой Stream, и отчитыйтесь из него.

Comment: Что-то подобное ранее я делал здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1144090/373567

Comment: @aepot, в моём случае хэширование измеряется минутами, а не часами. Но разве это имеет значение для способа вычисления прогресса?

Comment: `BitConverter.ToString` - старьё, освойте `Convert.ToHexString`

Comment: Я не знаю, что это за либа и зачем репортить прогресс конкретного файла, но если она простой стрим принимает, всегда можно написать свою обертку над ним [типа такой](https://github.com/tym32167/md5Reverse/blob/master/src/Md5Reverse.Lib/Utils/StreamSpy.cs)

Comment: @tym32167 это экстеншн под .NET 8, NuGet пакет System.IO.Hashing от мелкомягких

Comment: @aepot понял 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение:

```
string GetXxHash3(string filename, IProgress<long> progress)
{
    var hashAlgorithm = new XxHash3();
    using (Stream entryStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(4096); // use whatever chunk size you want
        int bytesRead;
        long totalRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = entryStream.Read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            hashAlgorithm.Append(buffer.AsSpan(0, bytesRead));
            totalRead += bytesRead;
            progress.Report(totalRead);
        }
        ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
    }
    return Convert.ToHexString(hashAlgorithm.GetHashAndReset());
}
```