# C# Декорирование клсса Stream

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, декоратор

Задача заключается в следующем: необходимо задекорировать класс Stream таким образом, чтобы он дублировал все прочитанные байты список. Например, при чтении файла, каждый байт записывался в созданный список. Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Ну вы можете получить массив байтов с файла `byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);` и потом распоряжаться ими как нужно вам (например смапить в список, как написали вы в вопросе)

Comment: Конечно, можно, но в условии к проектной работе написано, что нужно создать декоратор для такого случая)

Comment: Вот прям как описана задача, так и пишите декоратор. Создайте классический паттерн декоратор: класс, принимающий Stream и список. И в методах Read* он дополнительно пишет прочитанные данные в этот список.

Comment: вот [пример декоратора с логгированием](https://github.com/tym32167/md5Reverse/blob/master/src/Md5Reverse.Lib/Utils/StreamSpy.cs)

Comment: есть вот такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1143648/373567